# Using join in SQL Server 2005 express

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

I have a table in which I need to update based on the info from another. I wrote a select query that works great and shows exactly what I need to get rid of, but when when I try to change it to an update query, I get errors on Join. I hope it is a simple oversight that someone can point out to me.

Here is the select query that works:

```
select * 
from CustPayShdul
JOIN ARcreditapply 
ON ARcreditapply.AplyedRefNo = CustPayShdul.ReferNo AND ARcreditapply.AplyedLocation = CustPayShdul.LocationNo
AND ARcreditapply.sequence2 = CustPayShdul.Paysequence
where ARcreditapply.PaidDate < '1/1/2012' and ARcreditapply.PaidDate < CustPayShdul.InvDate
```

Here is the update query that returns an error:

```
update custpayshdul 
set custpayshdul.payablebalance = custpayshdul.amount
JOIN ARcreditapply 
ON ARcreditapply.AplyedRefNo = CustPayShdul.ReferNo AND ARcreditapply.AplyedLocation = CustPayShdul.LocationNo
AND ARcreditapply.sequence2 = CustPayShdul.Paysequence
where ARcreditapply.PaidDate < '1/1/2012' and ARcreditapply.PaidDate < CustPayShdul.InvDate
```

Comment: **WHAT** are those errors?? Please give us the exact and complete error message....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `FROM custpayshdul` before your join. Try:

```
update custpayshdul
set payablebalance = custpayshdul.amount
FROM custpayshdul
JOIN ARcreditapply 
ON ARcreditapply.AplyedRefNo = CustPayShdul.ReferNo AND ARcreditapply.AplyedLocation = CustPayShdul.LocationNo
AND ARcreditapply.sequence2 = CustPayShdul.Paysequence
where ARcreditapply.PaidDate < '1/1/2012' and ARcreditapply.PaidDate < CustPayShdul.InvDate
```

Comment: You are AWESOME!!!!!!!! Worked like a charm! That was driving me mad! Thank you soooooo much!

Comment: Glad to help! it would be awesome if you could also mark that as the answer ;)